# joined tables overwrite the columns

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db-table

While using `Zend_Db_Table`s and `Zend_Db_Table_Select` with `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql`, I am having a problem using a select query:

```
$rowset = $db->select()->from(array('a'=>'tablea'))
             ->columns(array('a.a'))
             ->join(array('b'=>'tableb'),'b.id = a.id', array('b.a'))
             ->query()->fetchAll();
```

Expected contents of rowset: (mainly the keys)

```
$rowset['a.a'] = "something";
$rowset['b.a'] = "somethingElse";
```

In the actual content of `$rowset`, only `$rowset['a']` exists, with no way to differentiate between the joined tables.

Any solutions to this?

---

When just doing a

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM tablea AS a
JOIN tableb AS b ON a.key = b.fkey";
$dbtable->getAdapter()->fetchAll($q);
```

I also don't get what I expect.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question?  By definition, array keys are unique, so your "Expected contents of rowset" isn't making sense to me.

Comment: When I use the `'tablename' AS 'alias'` syntax, I expect my results named like `alias.<col>`. They are then indeed unique. But this is not what happens here.

Comment: ah, but indeed I messed up with the second `$rowset['b.a']`

Comment: It looks like that query is broken - the second argument to join should be a string rather than an array.  I understand if you're editing sensitive information out of example code for purposes of asking your question, but double check what you've posted to make sure we can help you where you really need it.

Comment: @JeremyKendall: yeah, it's getting late. Did some more experimentation

Comment: Guy: LOL.  I hear ya.  OK, one thing at a time.  Did my answer below resolve the fact that you don't see the results from both tables?  If not, and this speaks to your edit, what exactly do you expect to see in your result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to differentiate between tables a and b when there are matching column names, you'll want to alias the columns in table b.  The join would then look something like:

```
->join(array('b' => 'tableb'), 'a.id = b.id', array('a_from_b' => 'b.a'))
```

Please note that the 'ON' condition should be a string, not an array.